# drawText to a specific postion of bitmap Android

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

I want to fill a credit card image with some text(name, surname,...) but i found problems to correctly find the starting position of the text.
I have marked my image with special pixels, I want to draw text at the start of this specific pixels but when I run the text is not aligned with them, I supposed that the specific pixel position that I calculated in the code is calculated starting from the first canvas pixel rather than the first bitmap pixel. How can I solve it? Thank you.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)this.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    final int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    final int h = bitmap.getHeight();
    int pixel;
    int redValue;
    int blueValue;
    int greenValue;

    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
            redValue = Color.red(pixel);
            blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
            greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
            if (redValue == 255 && greenValue == 254 && blueValue == 0){
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                paint.setTextSize(35);
                canvas.drawText("Some Text", x, y, paint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want evry pixel of bitmap?